# writing signals to serial port

Tags: c#, rs485, dmx512

I am trying to write data to a DMX receiver via USB to RS485 cable. I can see the correct data frames, but for the packet to follow the DMX protocol, I need a break and MAB signal. So my question is, is there a way to generate such signals? My thoughts were to write hi and lo signals with delays to the serial port but I have not found a way to do this in VS C#.

Comment: The DMX bus timing is far too critical to ever be able to generate it reliably on a regular PC.  You'll need to go shopping for a dedicated DMX controller, companies like Enttec are Sweetlight are in that business.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example (though not in .NET but you can translate it) here:

[How to control DmxSimple over serial](https://code.google.com/p/tinkerit/wiki/SerialToDmx)

And use the [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) class to send the data down your cable

Comment: If possible I would not like to use Arduino, I would also like to be able to customize the DMX packet, i.e. send packet with a different start byte. I don't see how I could use this method without using Arduino.

Comment: Translate the C code into C#.  Look at the data they are sending to the serial port.  I was using it as an example, you don't need an Arduino to talk to the DMX receiver.